# mySQL faster to search a single column? or two columns in series? or use a join?

Tags: mysql

I have the opportunity to make a table that could potentially contain millions if not billions of records eventually...  I know with big data, I should be moving towards something like Mongo/node.js but this is a prototype and I don't have enough time to learn that yet.

The MySQL table will hold coordinates in an X and Y fashion.
It could either look like this:

```
|   id|   x|   y|
|    0| 105| -12|
|    1|  23|  18|
|    2|-529|  -1|
```

or like this:

```
|   id|     coord|
|    0|  x105y-12|
|    1|    x23y18|
|    2|  x-529y-1|
```

Now, would it be faster to make double columns and either;

1. Search by X, then search by Y
2. Search with a JOIN for X&Y

Or would it be faster to search the single column in the second table?

Comment: always the firts .. keep you data correctly separated .. the time for  select a column or two is the same ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, Great to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely going to be faster to put the data in two columns, not the least being that you can define them as numeric (vs alpha) data types.

You *probably* want to create **a** multi-column on the two data columns, but indexing is a complex issue, particularly if you did get into the millions or billions of records level, and it has many factors. For a small prototype, it shouldn't be an issue.

You certainly may want to look into a no-sql solution (not sure what Node.js has to do with it), in particular for geo coords, check out the new [Geo API in
Redis](http://cristian.regolo.cc/2015/07/07/introducing-the-geo-api-in-redis.html).

(Note that a JOIN in MySql usually refers to searching across multiple tables, so you might want to use different language.)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the first option. I would also have indexes on those two columns if search should be fast and space is not an issue.

Comment: Good call, Thank you!